# Mobile sub menu expand/collapse is not working with voiceover

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

I have the following html.

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><span>Main item</span></li>
  <li>Main item 2
    <span>Main item 2</span>
    <span class="sub-menu-trigger"></span>
    <div class="menu-wrapper">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><span>Sub menu item</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On the `sub-menu-trigger` class I have the following css

```
display: block;
background: url(../images/icons/plus.png) center center/23px no-repeat;
width: 45px;
height: 36px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
transition: all .4s ease;
```

I have written the click even to expand the sub menu

```
$('.sub-menu-trigger').on('click', function(){
// some code
});
```

This works find when the voice over is not enabled. But with voice over enabled then it works for the first time only. Means when I expand it then I'm unable to close it nor I can expand another sub menu.

But when I replace the click event code to

```
$('.sub-menu-trigger').on('click touchstart', function(){
    // some code
});
```

Then the sub menu expand/collapse work fine when the voice over is enabled but without voice over then it is not working.

And also when voice over is enabled then I'm unable to click on the sub menu items.

What I'm doing wrong? is there a problem in my html or I'm missing some attributes? Can some one guide me with this?

Comment: Do you have a live page we can see?

Comment: Isnt't it a duplicate of your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972519/mobile-menu-is-not-opening-when-voice-over-enabled-on-ios ?